# How do I get a value in the `onchange` event of a Blockly custom block?

Tags: javascript, blockly

I am making a custom block for Blockly and need to validate the inputs. In the `onchange` event, I want to warn the user if they are entering an invalid value for the input.

Here is my block:

[image]

```
Blockly.Blocks['motor'] = {
    init: function() {
        this.setHelpUrl('http://www.example.com/');
        this.setColour(65);
        this.appendDummyInput()
            .appendField("motor( ");
        this.appendValueInput("port_number")
            .setCheck("Number");
        this.appendDummyInput()
            .appendField(");");
        this.setInputsInline(true);
        this.setPreviousStatement(true);
        this.setNextStatement(true);
        this.setTooltip('');
    },
    onchange: function(ev) {
        if (this.getFieldValue('port_number') > '3') {
            this.setWarningText('Port must be 0 - 3.');
        } else {
            this.setWarningText(null);
        }
    }
};
```

On the [Blockly Developers Page](https://developers.google.com/blockly/custom-blocks/defining-blocks#onchange), it has a basic example of getting an input value. However, I keep getting an `undefined` returned every time the `onchange` fires.

How can I handle validation for these inputs? I don't want to create a dropdown for the input because I need to be able to input from variables, int blocks, etc.

Comment: Have you solved this? If you have, please post. If you have not, you can always do console.log(this) to find out what's going on; or, better yet, set a breakpoint and evaluate. Or, in some cases, you can use `     var block = Blockly.selected;`

Comment: @ТаняТ. Thanks for the help, your comment did lead me to determine how to pull out the value of the input!

Comment: Did you use Blockly.selected? And do you know what your `this` was?

Comment: @ТаняТ. I did not need Blockly.selected because I already had an instance of the block. `this` was that instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to handle this, but it is working for me. I just access the input value using the `valueToCode` method. Then I can validate the input value.

> Note: The context of the `onchange` handler is the block, so passing
>   `this` as the first argument to `Blockly.C.valueToCode` will get the
>   value from the correct block.

```
Blockly.Blocks['motor'] = {
    init: function() {
        this.setHelpUrl('http://www.example.com/');
        this.setColour(65);
        this.appendDummyInput()
            .appendField("motor( ");
        this.appendValueInput("port_number")
            .setCheck("Number");
        this.appendDummyInput()
            .appendField(");");
        this.setInputsInline(true);
        this.setPreviousStatement(true);
        this.setNextStatement(true);
        this.setTooltip('');
    },
    onchange: function(ev) {
        var port_number = Blockly.C.valueToCode(this, 'port_number', Blockly.C.ORDER_ATOMIC);
        var valid = VALIDATE.motor_port_number(port_number);
        if (!valid) 
            alert("WARNING: The value for the motor port must be 0, 1, 2 or 3.");
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.getInputTargetBlock('port_number').toString()
```

Or:

```
this.getInputTargetBlock('port_number').getFieldValue(/*field_name*/)
```

Example:

```
   Blockly.Blocks['stop_actions'] = {
    init: function() {
        var actions_descriptors = [
            ['HOLD', 'hold'],
            ['COAST', 'coast']
        ];
        this.appendDummyInput()
            .appendField(new Blockly.FieldDropdown(actions_descriptors), 'action')
            .setAlign(Blockly.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        this.setOutput(true, 'String');
        this.setColour(60);
        this.setTooltip('Select the stop action');
    }
};

Blockly.Blocks['motor'] = {
    init: function() {
        this.appendValueInput('arg_stop_action')
            .appendField('Stop action')
            .setAlign(Blockly.ALIGN_RIGHT);
    },

    onchange: function(e) {
        this.getInputTargetBlock('arg_stop_action').getFieldValue('action')
    }
};
```